# My LSTM model gets stuck in 0.5 accuracy and 0.7 loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using many-to-one lstm model for sentiment classification. The dataset I am using is IMDB dataset. In order to vectorize the words I have decided to use [Glove](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) 100D representations.

**THE MODEL**

```
n_a = 128
def sentiment_model(embedding_layer,n_a):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        embedding_layer,
        LSTM(n_a, input_shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, 100), return_state = False),
        Dropout(0.25),
        Dense(64),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    return model

opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)    
modelo.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=opt,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**TRAINING THE MODEL**

```
modelo.fit(tokens_train,y_train[:,np.newaxis],epochs=10, verbose = 1)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
313/313 [==============================] - 63s 202ms/step - loss: 0.7008 - accuracy: 0.4948
Epoch 2/10
313/313 [==============================] - 64s 203ms/step - loss: 0.6980 - accuracy: 0.5084
Epoch 3/10
313/313 [==============================] - 66s 212ms/step - loss: 0.6966 - accuracy: 0.5016
Epoch 4/10
313/313 [==============================] - 69s 220ms/step - loss: 0.6965 - accuracy: 0.4983
Epoch 5/10
313/313 [==============================] - 67s 215ms/step - loss: 0.6959 - accuracy: 0.4970
Epoch 6/10
313/313 [==============================] - 69s 222ms/step - loss: 0.6954 - accuracy: 0.5028
Epoch 7/10
313/313 [==============================] - 68s 218ms/step - loss: 0.6964 - accuracy: 0.4985
Epoch 8/10
313/313 [==============================] - 68s 216ms/step - loss: 0.6976 - accuracy: 0.4965
Epoch 9/10
313/313 [==============================] - 68s 216ms/step - loss: 0.6959 - accuracy: 0.5048
Epoch 10/10
313/313 [==============================] - 68s 217ms/step - loss: 0.6962 - accuracy: 0.5059
```

**EDIT**
Im going to introduce the code I have implemented in order to vectorize the texts. (PD: I deleted the unsup folder)

```
reviews_train = load_files("aclImdb/train/",encoding='utf-8')
text_train, y_train = reviews_train.data, reviews_train.target
reviews_test = load_files("aclImdb/test/",encoding='utf-8')
text_test, y_test = reviews_test.data, reviews_test.target
text_train = text_train[:10000]
y_train = y_train[:10000]

MAX_WORDS = 512
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 500
tokenizador = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_WORDS) 
tokenizador.fit_on_texts(text_train)
tokens_train = tokenizador.texts_to_sequences(text_train)
tokens_test = tokenizador.texts_to_sequences(text_test)
tokens_train = pad_sequences(tokens_train, padding='post', maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
tokens_test = pad_sequences(tokens_test, padding='post', maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
```

After this, I created a dictionary with key words and values the embeddings of each word according to glove.6B.100d.txt. This dictionary is called embedding_words.

```
embeddings_words = {}
f = open('embedding/glove.6B.100d.txt', encoding="utf8")
for linea in f:
    elems = linea.split()
    word = elems[0]
    embedding = np.asarray(elems[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_words[word] = embedding
f.close()
```

Then, I created a embedding matrix, where each i-th row represents the i-th word of the vectorization, including this row the corresponding glove embedding.

```
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index)+1,EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, index in word_index.items():
    embedding = embeddings_words.get(word)
    if embedding is not None:
        embedding_matrix[index] = embedding
```

With this embedding layer, I created the embedding layer Im gonna use as the Input layer of the model.

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            trainable=False)
```

The output of the embedding layer returns a Tensor of shape (10000, 500, 100) as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you attach code of data preprocessing?

Comment: Add some background information, what problem are you trying to solve, how are giving the data to the model?

Comment: I have eddited the question in order to show the data preprocessing. I hope Its enough. Thank you guys. And sorry for my bad english It is not my native language.